# How to reorganize a schedule until midnight?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have the following schedule:

```
export default {
monday: {
    startTime: '11:00', // 11 am
    endTime: '03:00' // 03 am
},
tuesday: {
    startTime: '12:00', //12 am
    endTime: '18:30' // 6 pm
},
wednesday: {
    startTime: '10:00', //10 am
    endTime: '22:00' // 10 pm
},
thursday: {
    startTime: '11:00', // 11 am
    endTime: '21:30' // 9pm
},
friday: {
    startTime: '10:00', //10 am
    endTime: '19:00' // 7pm
}, 
    saturday: undefined,
    sunday: undefined
}
```

Please check the schedule for Monday. Imagine that a store opens at 11am and closes around 3am, but from midnight to 03am it's already Tuesday, since Monday ends at midnight.

With the schedule above, I would like to re-organize it by separating the time properly. Something like this:

```
monday: [
    {startTime: '11:00', endTime: '00:00' } // 11am, midnight
],
tuesday: [
    { startTime: '00:00', endTime: '03:00' }, // midnight, 03am
    { startTime: '11:00', endTime: '18:30' } // 11am, 6pm
]
```

The schedule can be changed to other start times and end times, so the code should adapt to these changes.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
componentDidMount(){
    let newSchedule: any;
    const schedule = this.props.schedule; // the whole schedule

    const startTime = Object.keys(schedule)
            .filter((key) => schedule[key])  
            .map((key:string) => moment(schedule[key].startTime, 'HH:mm'))
    console.log(startTime) // every startTime

    const endTime = Object.keys(schedule)
            .filter((key) => schedule[key])  
            .map((key:string) => moment(schedule[key].endTime, 'HH:mm'))
    console.log(endTime) // every endTime

    if (endTime < startTime) {
        console.log('yes') // works
    }

    if (endTime < startTime) {
        console.log('yep') // works
    }

}
```

I thought about iterating the object, so I can get each day of the week and get each start time and end time. What I don't know what to do next is to separate the schedules until midnight.

How can I achieve this result in JS? I can also work with Moment JS. :)

Comment: Seems to miss any logic that checks for `endTime` before `startTime` and less than 24

Comment: I just implemented a simple conditional statement, just to check if works, except the before 24hr check. I updated the question @charlietfl

Comment: No because they are arrays....you need to check each instance and modify existing object and create new one if applicable as you loop over `Object.keys`

Comment: Psuedo code: `Object.keys(sched).forEach((k,i) => if(sched[k].end < sched[k].start){// modify})`

Comment: Hm, okay. For before 24h, maybe I should use Moment JS? like `if (midnight.isBefore(endTime){})`?

Comment: If you already import moment it would probably make it easy yes. I wouldn't import it just for this though. Working with numbers shown should be relatively easy also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191102/discussion-between-rcohen-and-charlietfl).